# Serving uncommon static files, such as .properties, in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, static-files

I'm using Pdf.js viewer in a Blazor Server application, but the middleware is having a hard time serving .properties file needed by the viewer so I added a second middleware as so:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {".properties", "text/plain"}
    })
});
```

If I try to add the new ContentTypeProvider in the first middleware, then it overrides the default ContentTypeProvider, which means all of the other static files don't get served anymore. Is this the way that it should be done? How can I serve uncommon static files?

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to resolve the issue because it's overriding the ContentTypeProvider and all other static files are not being served.

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to add the new ContentTypeProvider in the first middleware,
> then it overrides the default ContentTypeProvider, which means all of
> the other static files don't get served anymore. Is this the way that
> it should be done? How can I serve uncommon static files?

In order to serve any custom file type or replacement of existing file type we should use [Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles.fileextensioncontenttypeprovider.mappings?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-staticfiles-fileextensioncontenttypeprovider-mappings) property of [FileExtensionContentTypeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles.fileextensioncontenttypeprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class. According to your shared code snippet and description if you would like to introduce new mime type then, you should do as following:

```cs
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".properties"] = "text/html";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

**Note:** In case of unknown file type `ServeUnknownFileTypes` property should be set to true. For instance, `ServeUnknownFileTypes = true`. You can [get more details here in the official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#fileextensioncontenttypeprovider)